# Is it okay to use a polarized capacitor at low enough frequency?

Tags: capacitor, inductor

I have solenoids with values between 0.5-10 mH. In order to make an LC resonant circuit at 1 kHz, I need capacitors in the value of anywhere between 2 to 50 microfarads.

The problem is that I can't seem to find non-polarized capacitors higher than 1 uF. Is it just me? I'm not talking about chip capacitors for the moment. (I can't really use them since I'm using a breadboard.)

I suppose this begs the question: Is it okay to use polarized capacitor if the frequency is low enough? If so, how low? What about the voltage level, does that matter as well?

I imagine there are others who encountered this problem.

Comment: You could solder thin solid wire legs at ceramic SMD capacitors for the use in a breadboard.

Comment: Why do you need to make resonant circuits with solenoids? Unless those solenoids are just coils that aren’t coupled to moving parts like in relays or valves.

Answer (score 1):

Using a polarised capacitor is about the voltage, not the frequency.

If you can limit the negative voltage to be as small as possible, for electrolytics less than one volt, preferrably less, then you should be OK.

There are two common ways to use polarised capacitors in a large voltage swing environment. The easy way, and the better way.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLSUBQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The effective value of the non-polarised capacitor will be C/2, or 50 uF for the circuits shown.

As the capacitors are exposed to an AC voltage signal from end to end, the diodes will rectify and 'pump up' the middle terminal. Even silicon diodes will limit the reverse voltage across the capacitors to <1 V, schottky diodes will be better. This will distort the operation of a 'non-polarised capacitor' for the few cycles that it takes to charge the middle terminal. If you have a varying AC signal, maybe audio, then leakage between the peaks will mean that on each new peak, a little rectifying current will flow, which may be audible as distortion.

If you bias the middle terminal with a supply, then you can ensure positive bias on each capacitor, regardless of signal amplitude. Choose R1 large enough to not compromise your signal, but small enough to handle the leakage current of two large capacitors. The diodes are there to protect the capacitors should a large AC voltage be applied before the bias has had time to rise to its design voltage.

Note, the capacitor symbols are non-polarised. For all the convenience that this built-in schematic editor offers, it doesn't have a polarised capacitor symbol. I've added little '+'s to make up for it.

Comment: Holy moly, thanks a lot. If you don't mind, how big should the bias voltage should be? Does it depend on the AC voltage level? (Let's say it's 36 Vpp) Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: @M.K.Saunders The bias voltage can be any larger than the peak of the AC (to avoid  under-voltage) and less than the capacitor's voltage rating when added to the peak voltage (to avoid over-voltage). I'm always nervous about thinking I understand what people mean when they say Vpp. If you mean than an ideal non-polar capacitor would be charged to voltages of +18 V and - 18 V in operation, then you would use a bias voltage of at least 18 V, ideally a little more for margin, and use caps rated for more than 18 V + Vbias. Perhaps 63 V caps, 25 V bias, or 40 V and 20 V if you're feeling cheap

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thank you so much for taking your time answering this!